# batch file to read ever element in my .xml

Tags: batch-file

i'm trying to use a batch file to read through all the elements of my .xml file to retrieve the file path and execute them in order like a playlist. heres an example of my .xml file:

```
<Sunday>
<id>1</id>
<filePath>\\MOVIESERVER\movie1.mkv</filePath>
</Sunday>
<Sunday>
<id>2</id>
<filePath>\\MOVIESERVER\movie2.avi</filePath>
</Sunday>
<Sunday>
<id>3</id>
<filePath>\\MOVIESERVER\movie3.avi</filePath>
</Sunday>
<Sunday>
<id>4</id>
<filePath>\\MOVIESERVER\Movie4.avi</filePath>
</Sunday>
</dataroot>
```

right now i'm using this batch file but it only reads the first element "\MOVIESERVER\movie1.mkv"
how do i get it to either loop through or line by line pull out the filepaths in order?

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=<>" %%a in ('type "C:\VlcTV\VLCPlaylists\Programs\Version_3.0\00-Sun.xml" ^|find /i "<filepath>" ') do set "var=%%a"
```

any suggestions will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to activate the delayed expansion :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=2 delims=<>" %%a in ('type "C:\VlcTV\VLCPlaylists\Programs\Version_3.0\00-Sun.xml" ^|find /i "<filepath>" ') do (
 set var="%%a"
 echo !var!)
```

Comment: nothing changed when i added the "setlocal enabledelayedexpansion" to the batch file. it still doesn't read each file path in order.

Comment: i actually noticed i was wrong about it reading only the first element it appears its actually reading the 4th or last element. and when i added the "setlocal enabledelayedexpansion" nothing changed. i'm looking for a way to ouput the filepaths in order. is there a way to set each line(filepath) to a seperate variable?

Comment: after playing with it some more i see it is reading all the elements but it only echos the last one. is there a way to echo each element (filePath)?

Comment: Very strange ! It have to echos all the element.